# Nice RSS Feed URLs for each custom post type

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rss

By default WP seems to display all posts of all types in the main RSS feed.
You have to add a post_type query variable to show post of a certain type...

So how can I turn this:

`http://site.com/feed/?post_type=book`

into

`http://site.com/feed/books/`

?

And if possible rewrite `http://site.com/feed/` to `http://site.com/feed/blog/`, which should display only normal posts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `'has_archive' => TRUE` in `register_post_type()` the post type will have its own feed on `/books/feed/` and its items are not included in the main feed.

#### Example plugin

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE13006 feed for CPT demo
*/
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

add_action( 'init', 'wpse13006_register' );

// Call wp-admin/options-permalink.php once after activation to make permalinks work
function wpse13006_register()
{
    register_post_type(
        'wpse13006'
    ,   array (
            'has_archive'         => TRUE
        ,   'label'               => 'wpse13006'
        ,   'public'              => TRUE
        ,   'publicly_queryable'  => TRUE
        ,   'query_var'           => 'wpse13006'
        ,   'rewrite'             => array ( 'slug' => 'wpse13006' )
        ,   'show_ui'             => TRUE
        ,   'show_in_menu'        => TRUE
        ,   'supports'            => array ( 'title', 'editor' )
        )
    );
}
```

Create one post, publish and view it. If you go up one level to `/wpse13006/` now, you’ll find the feed at `/wpse13006/feed/`. The post will not show up in the main feed.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about these URLs even though I had has_archive on (but custom post types are still included in the main feed). Do you know if there's a function that returns the rss URL for each post type, or you need to build it manually?

Comment: @One Trick Pony Strange, the CPTs are never in my main feed. `get_post_type_archive_feed_link()` should return the feed URI, but it returned always FALSE in my tests.

Comment: This didnt work for me