# Rewrite custom post type rss feed links

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, feed, permalinks

I am looking for a way to rewrite my custom post type feed located at

`http://localhost:8888/feed/?post_type=post`

to

`http://localhost:8888/feed/portfolio`

[this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13006/nice-rss-feed-urls-for-each-custom-post-type) post suggests using

`http://localhost:8888/portfolio/feed/`

which is not the main feed but the comments feed, any ideas?

`http://localhost:8888/portfolio/feed`

currently the above goes to comments as well.

Comment: Is your `/portfolio/` address a real custom post type archive (with `has_archive`), or a "fake" one with a stub page (pre-3.1 I think)?

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a plugin or `functions.php`:

```
function feed_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $feed_rules = array(
        'feed/portfolio'    =>  'index.php?post_type=post&feed=rss2'
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'feed_rewrite' );
```

When you've done that, go to the permalinks page and resave to flush your old rules and regenerate them

Remember, when changing rewrite rules to use the monkeyman rewrite analyser tool plugin to check what rules are used for which URLs

Comment: This turns out to be a solution at one of the many other things I wanted to do. :) Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

If you have the archive on CPT to true, that creat WP always a feed, the nice URL is only usable, after you refresh the permalinks via Settings in Backend or via a function in your code. Important is the name of your CPT, should the name is "portfolio". If you have another name, then you must create a rewrite, maybe with `wp_rewrite()` or via rules inside the .htaccess File, if it is a a Apache server.