# add_feed rewrite overwriting standard permalinks

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, feed

By doing a simple:

```
add_feed( 'schedule', 'my_schedule_feed' );
```

I have created a feed at `/feed/schedule/`... easy.

But when I go to `/schedule/` (which is a page) it is now showing the feed!

Looking at the rewrite rules I see this:

```
[feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom|schedule)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
[(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom|schedule)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
```

This seems really odd. Why would WordPress overwrite existing page rules with the feed, instead of just using only the `/feed/` base as expected?

**Update**: I have tried this as suggested by [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48136/76440), and flushing the permalinks, but while it shows up in the rewrites, it does not show the feed at `/feed/schedule/`

```
function add_feed_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feednames = array( 'schedule', 'calendar' );
    $feeds = implode( '|', $feednames);
    $feed_rule = array(
        'feed/(' . $feeds . ')/?$' => 'index.php?&feed=$matches[1]'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge( $wp_rewrite->rules, $feed_rule );    
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_feed_rewrites' );

add_action( 'do_feed_schedule', 'my_schedule', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'do_feed_calendar', 'my_calendar', 10, 2 );
```

Any ideas on how to get this working without the initial conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `add_feed()`, then you can use `add_rewrite_rule()`:

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^feed/(schedule|calendar)/?$',
        'index.php?feed=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
} );

add_action( 'do_feed_schedule', function () {
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' ); // dummy type just for testing
    echo 'Yay, it works!';
} );
```

#### But regarding the original question about `add_feed()`..

> Why would WordPress overwrite existing page rules with the feed,
>   instead of just using only the `/feed/` base as expected?

So that `example.com/schedule` would serve your custom feed, just like standard feed URLs such as `example.com/feed`. But WordPress does create the (proper) rules having the `feed/` base for custom feed URLs like `example.com/feed/schedule`.

Therefore you shouldn't use `schedule` as the slug of your Page, or if you have/need to, then you can alter the feed rewrite so that the `example.com/schedule` will serve the Page instead of your feed:

- If you know the exact rule/RegEx:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function ( $rules ) {
      $rules2 = [];
      foreach ( $rules as $regex => $query ) {
          if ( '(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom|schedule)/?$' === $regex ) { // it has 'schedule'
              $rules2['(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = $query;       // so let's remove it
          } else {
              $rules2[ $regex ] = $query;
          }
      }
      return $rules2;
  } );
  ```
- Otherwise, try something dynamic like this:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function ( $rules ) {
      global $wp_rewrite;

      $feeds = $wp_rewrite->feeds;         // original feeds
      $pages = [ 'schedule', 'calendar' ]; // page slugs list
      $feeds2 = array_diff( $feeds, $pages );

      $rules2 = [];
      $feeds = implode( '|', $feeds );
      $feeds2 = implode( '|', $feeds2 );

      foreach ( $rules as $regex => $query ) {
          if ( '(' . $feeds . ')/?$' === $regex ) {
              $rules2[ '(' . $feeds2 . ')/?$' ] = $query;
          } else {
              $rules2[ $regex ] = $query;
          }
      }

      return $rules2;
  } );
  ```

Note that I use the `foreach` so that the rule stays in its original position. And another possible option is that just move the rule to a position after the Page rewrite rules. But I haven't yet tried that and the above code should be enough as a workaround..

---

And if I'm not mistaken, here's the code which WordPress use to generate the rule that's being altered in the above function:

```php
// Create query for /(feed|atom|rss|rss2|rdf) (see comment near creation of $feedregex).
$feedmatch2 = $match . $feedregex2;
$feedquery2 = $feedindex . '?' . $query . '&feed=' . $this->preg_index( $num_toks + 1 );
```

See the [source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L989).

Comment: thank you for the detailed response!!! I'll definitely get it working now, rewrites are one thing that really have me scratching my head. I guess I was surprised I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere, everywhere just seems to say "your feed will be available via `/feed/`" which is not very informative...
This is for a plugin so I don't have control over what pages may already exist, and schedule is *very* likely to exist already in the context I'm working on, so I simply can't have it overwriting pages at all.

Comment: That's understandable. :) And actually, there's another option when using `add_feed()` if you don't want to alter the rule generated by WordPress: `add_rewrite_rule( '^(schedule|calendar)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top' )` - but you may need to add other rules for that Pages, depending on things like whether paginated requests/URLs (e.g. `example.com/schedule/2`) should be enabled.